# How can i change ip without proxy?

Tags: c#, .net, ip, spoofing

I'm sending data to an API server. I have to send hundreds of requests per minute. The load balancer server is blocking my IP address and proxy addresses. The request I send is not an attack or the like. I'm using it for testing. The response from the server is not important to me. How can I send a different IP to the server without the proxy?

I used a proxy, but it was blocked immediately.

```
using ( WebClient wc = new WebClient())
    { 
        wc.Proxy = webproxy;

        wc.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        wc.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.UserAgent] = useragent; // from txt file 
        wc.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Accept] = "*/*";
        wc.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.AcceptLanguage] = "tr-TR-TR";
        wc.CachePolicy = new RequestCachePolicy(RequestCacheLevel.NoCacheNoStore);

        var result = wc.UploadString("https://api.mysite.com", "birthYear=2000&birthDate=20&birthMonth=5&hourFormat=24");
        wc.Dispose();

    }
```

I need to send Api a different ip address without using a proxy

Comment: Use a VPN, or disconnect and reconnect (if you don't have a static IP) in the hopes that your ISP assign you a new address.

Comment: Sounds like a *DOS*, i mean, if you dont care about the response, send it to any address. i mean, why dont you set up a local endpoint and test. This all seems a little suspect

Comment: John. I tried to use VPN but it takes too long to change ip. Sometimes it can't be successful.
General. The api I sent the request runs on my own server. I don't attack. I cannot run the API in the local zone.

Can I submit a web request with IP Spoofing?